# Avoid repeating pattern in vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have this huge annoying component that needs to be repeated many times in the parent template because the parent template is using v-if. Here is the component code:

```
<SelectCard
  v-for="(channel, index) in category.visibleChannels"
  :key="index + '-' + channel.id"
  :channel="channel"
  :channel-selected="isSelected(channel.id)"
  :read-more-details="channelInfoDetails"
  @select="onAddChannel"
  @deselect="onRemoveChannel"
  @read-more-changed="setChannelInfoDetails"
/>
```

The only thing that changes between each time I render the template is what array I loop over....
Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
<template>
<div
    ref="channels"
    class="channels"
  >
    <div v-if="showCategories">
      <div
        v-for="category in sliderCategories"
        :key="category.name"
      >
        <h3 v-text="category.name" />
        <div
          v-if="category.showAll"
          class="channel-list show-all"
          :class="channelListSize"
        >
          <ul>
            <SelectCard looping over category.contents  />
          </ul>
        </div>
        <ChannelSlider
          v-else
          :category="category"
          @visible-updated="setVisibleChannels"
        >
          <SelectCard looping over category.visibleChannels  />
        </ChannelSlider>
        <div class="show-all-link">
          <a
            :class="category.showAll?'arrow-up':'arrow-down'"
            class="link"
            @keyup.enter="toggleShowAll(category.name, !category.showAll)"
            @click="toggleShowAll(category.name, !category.showAll)"
            v-text="showAllText(category.showAll)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <div v-if="showNoSearchResult">
        <SomeComponent with some props/>
      </div>
      <div :class="channelListSize" class="channel-list">
        <ul>
          <SelectCard looping over updatedChannels  />
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div
      ref="someref"
      class="someClass"
      :style="{top: channelInfoDetails.top + 'px', position: 'absolute'}"
    >
      <AnotherComponent with some props/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

So my template becomes HUGE because the SelectCard code has so many props.

Is there a way I can put SelectCard in a method in the parent code, so that I can just call a function with the array to use or something? Or is there another solution that I don't know of?

Comment: Is the markup for each branch really just a pair of `<div>` elements containing the `SelectCard`? Or was that a simplification for the purposes of asking the question?

Comment: @skirtle , it is for simplofication... each v-if/v-else has more template inside. None of them have the same content other than the SelectCard.

Comment: I've updated the sample template to make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a solution here that is as simple as you might like. But there are some possibilities.

You can reduce it down slightly by using the object form of `v-bind` and `v-on`. For the `v-bind` you'd need to introduce a method to return the object as your props depend on `channel` and `index`, so they would need passing to the method. This would cut it down a bit but it isn't great. The object form of the `is` attribute might also be an option. That might squeeze it down a little further but at the expense of clarity.

Another approach would be to introduce another component and then use slots for the `SelectCard`. e.g.:

```html
<div>
  <div v-if="conditionA">
    <div v-if="conditionA-A">
      <slot />
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <slot />
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <div v-if="conditionB-A">
      <slot />
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <slot />
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

You'd then pass the `SelectCard` in as the slot contents, with a computed property to make the array dynamic.

One problem with this approach is that you may find yourself having to pass a lot of stuff around between the various layers of component to get it working.

A further option is to convert everything to a `render` function. You definitely can do what you're trying to do using a `render` function but that would come at the expense of having to forgo using a template. Whether that is really a problem would depend on the complexity of the rest of the template.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This was my fear. I updated the sample template to show how complex it is. There are so many different variations. And the template is completely useless to read in full version (as you might have guessed after seeing the new example). I was hoping the make the SelectCard part smaller to at least help it become a lot smaller... It seems like Vue lack flexibility in template rendering compared to for example React. And I am worried that we went for the wrong framework for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the logic of the `v-if's` into a computed property that returns the correct array that you want to pass as . props to the `SelectCard`
something like:

```
<SelectCard :arr="arrayToRender"/>
...
computed: {
       arrayToRender(){
           if (ConditionA){ return Array_A}
           if ....
    }
```

Comment: This is not possible unfortunately, as there are more code inside each v-if div than you see in my example... I just wanted to simplify my example... No v-if/v-else has the same content inside except this huge SelectCard thing....

Comment: even if you need  to break it up into a few computed properties then it is still better than polluting the template imo.